# Python 2.7 GAE app.yaml Getting 404 Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, yaml

Below is the code of my `app.yaml` file.  If I go to `localhost:8080/` my `index.app` loads correctly.  If I go to `localhost:8080/index.html` I get a 404 error.  If I go to any other page for example `localhost:8080/xxxx` the `not_found.app` loads correctly.  Why am I getting a 404 Error for the `/index\.html` case?

Thanks!

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /index\.html
  script: index.app

- url: /
  script: index.app

- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets

- url: /*
  script: not_found.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Code from index.py

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):

template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')

self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)

The fix was located in the bolded text!

Comment: why are you escaping the '.'?

Comment: I thought regular expression reference was used, so I needed to escape the period to suppress the special meaning.

Comment: What do your handlers in `index.app` look like?

Comment: with jinja2 the html should be referenced from within the code,should it not? "jinja.render_template("index.html")"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `app` variable in `index` does not have a handler for `index.html`. For instance:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])
```

If your application gets routed to `index`, it will look through the handlers defined and try to find a match to `/index.html`. In this example, if you go to `/`, it will work fine since that handler is defined; however if you go to `index.html`, GAE doesn't know which class to call, and it therefore returns a 404. As a simple test, try

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/index\.html', MainPage)
])
```

Since this is ostensibly a handler for anyone typing `index.html` or any other permutation of `index.`, you could use something like this to capture a broader array of cases (because internally, you can just route using `/` if you need to):

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/index\..*', MainPage)
])
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it! This is my first project with python instead of java.

Comment: @mike29892 No problem at all, happy to help - good luck with everything.